# Magento: How to position Newsletter box above footer wrapper?

Tags: newsletter

I am new to Magento and just starting to create own package and theme. What is a good practice to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Just got the answer that really works.

On footer.phtml, add this code above `<div class="footer-container">.....`

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('newsletter/subscribe')->setTemplate('newsletter/subscribe.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```